# Outputting two variables on a single line without changes to the variables

Tags: powershell, datetime, timezone

Inexperienced with PowerShell, here's a snippet that takes a timestamp in UTC (Zulu) and converts it to local time.

```ps
#input format:  '2024-03-20 19:26 Z'
param ($timestamp)
$result = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date -Date $timestamp), (Get-TimeZone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id))
Write-Output $result
```

This gets me the output:

> Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM

Now I want to add on the end of this output the local 3-letter time zone abbreviation (e.g. PST)

I found this command and it gets me close:

```ps
$localtzid = -join ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id.Split() | Foreach-Object {$_[0]})
"Time: {0:T} $tz" -f (Get-Date)
```

..gets me the time on one line and then the 3-letter abbreviation on the next line.

What I want to achieve is this:

> Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM PST

I've tried `Write-Output "$($result) $($localtzid)"` - changes the format entirely.  I've tried `Write-Output $result, $localtzid -join ','` - changes the format entirely.  I tried `concat`... I tried so many things.

Comment: Yes, $localtzid holds the value PST.

When I use your suggested format for the output it changes it from the desired output that includes the day of the week and the month to the following:

03/20/2024 12:26:00 PST -- so yes it adds the PST to the end of the output.. BUT..

The goal is:  

Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM PST

Thanks!

Comment: `'{0:F} {1}'  -f $result, $localized `.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: `'{0:F} {1}'  -f (Get-Date), ( -join ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id.Split() | Foreach-Object {$_[0]}))`

Comment: ```lang-ps

# input format:  '2024-03-20 19:26 Z'

param ($timestamp)$result = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date -Date $timestamp), (Get-TimeZone | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id))

Write-Output "$($result) $(-join ([System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id.Split() | Foreach-Object {$_[0]}))"
```

The output from this is:  03/20/2024 12:26:00 PST
The desired output is:     Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM PST

Comment: no, when I say input format I mean what $timestamp looks like coming into the script as the only input parameter.  The issue I'm having is without format of the output -- the input gets processed properly by the function that converts it from GMT(Z) to my local timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that time-zone *names*, including initialisms such as `PST`, aren't universally standardized, I  suggest formatting your date with a *UTC offset*, (e.g. `-07:00`) instead:

```
& {
  param ([string] $timestamp)
  $localTime = [datetime] $timestamp
  $localTime.ToString('F') + ' ' + $localTime.ToString('zzz')
} '2024-03-20 19:26 Z'
```

E.g., in the US Pacific time zone the output is:
`Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM -07:00`

---

If you still want to use an initialism such as `PST` and derive it from the initial letters of the full name of the local time zone, more work is needed:

```
& {
  param ($timestamp)
  $time = [datetimeoffset] [datetime] $timestamp
  $localTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local
  $isDstTime = $time.Offset -ne $localTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset
  $timeZoneName = ($localTimeZone.StandardName, $localTimeZone.DaylightName)[$isDstTime]
  $time.ToString('F') + ' ' + (-join (-split $timeZoneName).ForEach({ $_[0] }))
} '2024-03-20 19:26 Z'
```

This should result in `Wednesday, March 20, 2024 12:26:00 PM PDT` in the US Pacific time zone.
Note that `PDT` (from `Pacific Daylight Time` rather than `PST` (from `Pacific Standard Time`) is used, because the timestamp falls into the daylight-saving period.

Comment: Your longer snippet rocks!  I'm safe using the 4 U.S. time zones.. I live in a motorhome and don't plan to drive to Hawaii.